# How can I get notified of updates to Python packages in a unified way?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I work on a Python web application with 20+ dependency packages. I'd love to somehow get feeds of updates for all of these packages, so that I could look at their changelogs and update quickly if the package fixes important bugs or potential security vulnerabilities. Is there a way for me to do this without hunting down the project homepage RSS feed (if one exists) for all 20 packages individually?

Ideally I'd like to be able to slurp our `requirements.txt` file and construct a feed automatically, but I'd settle for just manually curating a list of RSS feeds or manually subscribing some email address to a bunch of email lists.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=rss (last 40 updated packages on pypi)

Comment: Thanks! I don't want updates for the thousands of packages I'm not subscribed to though.

Comment: you could run `pip list --outdated -l` to list non-global packages in the current virtualenv that could be updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I subscribe to updates of a package on PyPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395151/how-can-i-subscribe-to-updates-of-a-package-on-pypi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github seems to have launched this feature (for other languages too!) since I posted this. See [here](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-and-updating-vulnerable-dependencies-in-your-repository/).

Comment: Assuming you have a language they support and use the specifications of that language for dep management, like a requirements.txt file in your repo for python.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe https://requires.io/ is interesting to you?

It shows the status of all your dependencies and alerts you for security/outdated ones as well.

See here for example https://requires.io/github/edx/edx-platform/requirements/?branch=master

Comment: This would be more suitable as a comment.

Comment: @Frontear can you elaborate on why you think answer is more suited as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

If the Python packages is on PyPI, you can use [libraries.io](https://libraries.io/) to select packages you want release emails for.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622080/3585557) to a related question has additional details.