# How to release python behave module to python package index?

Tags: python, python-3.6

[python behave module](https://pypi.org/project/behave/) is currently at version 1.2.5.

However, behave version 1.2.5 has problems when run with Python 3.6.x.

When running behave under Python 3.6.x you get output like the following:

```
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/behave_runner.py", line 281, in <module>
>      my_config = configuration.Configuration(command_args=command_args)
>    File "/Users/jkroub/.virtualenvs/gs-quality-control-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/behave/configuration.py", line 601, in __init__
>      self.name_re = self.build_name_re(self.name)
>    File "/Users/jkroub/.virtualenvs/gs-quality-control-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/behave/configuration.py", line 665, in build_name_re
>      return re.compile(pattern, flags=(re.UNICODE | re.LOCALE))
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 233, in compile
>      return _compile(pattern, flags)
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 301, in _compile
>      p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
>      p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 865, in parse
>      p.pattern.flags = fix_flags(str, p.pattern.flags)
>  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 832, in fix_flags
>      raise ValueError("cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern")
>  ValueError: cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern
```

You can get things working with Python 3.6.x if you build from the development branch in git and install locally:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/behave/behave
```

You then update your requirements.txt to have:

```
behave==1.2.6.dev0
```

Q: When will this development behave module (1.2.6) be deployed to the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org)?

Q: How can you track this release map?

Q: Is there a better (more appropriate) place to ask this type of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: When will this development behave module (1.2.6) be deployed to the Python Package Index?

I guess nobody other than the maintainers of the behave project knows that.

> Q: How can you track this release map?

you could watch its GitHub project, or refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395151/how-can-i-subscribe-to-updates-of-a-package-on-pypi).

> Q: Is there a better (more appropriate) place to ask this type of question?

SO is not a good place IMO, you'd better go ask directly on its GitHub issue.